# jstree I need fire $.vakata.dnd.start with multiple drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

how I can make multiple drag and drop in jstree?
I need drag external div to jstree
I have jstree and 3 div(s)   I need select the 3 divs and drag into jstree , means I need make multiple drags  to jstree

I need fire $.vakata.dnd.start with multiple external drag how I can use it

my code is

> $('.dragDiv').on('mousedown', function (e) {
>           return $.vakata.dnd.start(e, {
>               'jstree': true,
>               'obj': $(this),
>               'nodes': [{
>                   id: this.id,
>                   text: $(this).text()
>               }]
>           }, '' + $(this).text() + '+');
>       });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an array for `nodes`. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/DGAF4/495/

Make sure you are using v.3.1.1 (the latest), as there was a bug with previous versions that did not allow for foreign items to be dropped.

The crucial bit of this demo is this:

```
$(document).on('mousedown touchstart', '.dragDiv.selected', function (e) {
    var nodes = [];
    $('.dragDiv.selected').each(function () {
        nodes.push({ id : this.id, text : this.innerHTML });
    });
    return $.vakata.dnd.start(e, { 'jstree': true, 'nodes': nodes }, ...
});
```

Comment: can I change the text displaying when I select and drag "2 items" to other word?